# How to check if a string input has a certain letter and then list a variable that's attached to that letter?

Tags: python

I'm doing a groklearning challenge and am currently stuck on this one question. Any help is appreciated!

[This is the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQr0y.png)

This is my current code:

```
order = input('Order: ')
for i in order:
  if 'h' in order:
    print('Ham')
    if 'p' in order:
      print('Pepperoni')
      if 'c' in order:
        print('Capsicum')
        if 'o' in order:
          print('Onion')
          if 'm' in order:
            print('Mushroom')
  else:
    print('MORE CHEESE!')
```

I have no idea where to begin or what to do. Thanks in advance! If the image link doesn't work please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Python dictionary would be a nice way to handle this.

```
toppings = {
    "h": "Ham",
    "p": "Pepperoni",
    "c": "Capsicum",
    "o": "Onion",
    "m": "Mushroom"}
```

Then use the dictionary's `get` method in order to supply the "MORE CHEESE" default for unrecognized keys:

```
for letter in input('Order: '):
    print toppings.get(letter, "MORE CHEESE!")
```